# Magento set product as variable

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to use `array_map()` method in my code, but i need to pass an array and the '**product**' object.
There's solutions to do it but **my question** here is : if it's a good practice, or how horrible is to do something like:

```
[...]
private $myproduct;
[...]
$this->setMyproduct($product);
[...]
$product = $this->getMyproduct();
[...]
```

My doubt is if php save the object again, what looks like a lot of work for the code, or if only save a reference to it and it's fast and a good manner to have my product where i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine, Magento/PHP will store the reference to the product, and will not load it everytime you access the variable, if that's what you're asking.

Another way to pass a persistent variable is to use Magento's register functionality:

`Mage::register('current_product', $product);`

and use this to retrieve it again:

`Mage::registry('current_product');`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use `array_map()` and need to pass an array and the product `object`

Like this `array_map(callable, array(product, product))`? Then you should start with a product collection:

```
public function method()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
        $collection->getSelect(),
        array(array($this, 'callback'))
    );
}

public function callback($args)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setData($args['row']);
    // your logic here
    // ...
}
```